# Serlog.Sinks.Graylog is not writing logs to graylog dashboard. I am working in dotnet core. I have setup dashboard inputs and streams accordingly

Tags: logging, serilog, graylog

```
var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration();

loggerConfig
   .Enrich.FromLogContext()
   .Enrich.WithProperty("source", "xxx-yyy")
   .Enrich.WithProperty("test", "test9999");

loggerConfig.WriteTo.Graylog(new GraylogSinkOptions
{
    HostnameOrAddress = "127.0.0.1:9000",
    Port = 12201
});
```

Comment: Are errors being emitted to the [SelfLog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics) ? https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Reliability is worth being aware of too. And some guesses: why is there a port in `HostnameOrAddress` and also a `Port`; are those ports definitely enabled in your environment?

Comment: I am running these in Docker environment. These ports are set. And I am able to log errors in local file but it is failing when i log into graylog dashboard.

Comment: any follow up on this?

Comment: There is no "follow up". I know zero about Graylog etc., but I suggested some things to try, hinting at bits of information that you could add to your question in order to assist someone with expertise in analysing something like this should they come along. Bottom line is you're going to have to troubleshoot this by narrowing down what's going wrong bit by bit until a conclusion is reached -- that's the job. In general I'd say it's safe to assume that a Serilog sink can be trusted to work given a correctly configured environment.

Answer (score 0):

`HostnameOrAddress` only needs the domain or IP, so remove the `:9000` part from that.
You've set the correct port in `12201` already. 9000 is only for the WebGUI.